# Why incomplete results from an outerJoin sliding window of KStreams is not flushed until new unrelated records arrive later?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Sample reproducing this problem: https://github.com/codependent/kstream-multijoin

I have three topics and a KStream application reading from them.

[image]

x, y, and z will get messages and I want to process them using a window in the KStream app.

The point is, in the same window sometimes I'll get messages from only one topic, two topics, or event the three of them at the same time:

```
Window 1 ---> merged(z)
Window 2 ---> merged(x + z)
Window 3 ---> merged(x + y + z)
Window 4 ---> merged(x)
...
```

Can you join more than two topics (KStreams) at the same time in a window?

Does it support the processing shown in the window above?

**UPDATE:**
So far I tried this:

```
    public KStream<String, String> joinedKStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> streamX = kStreamBuilder.stream("x");
        KStream<String, String> streamY = kStreamBuilder.stream("y");
        KStream<String, String> streamZ = kStreamBuilder.stream("z");

        KStream<String, String> stream = streamX
                .leftJoin(streamY, (s, s2) -> {
                    logger.info("Join x + y: {}-{}", s, s2);
                    return s + s2;
                }, JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(20)))
                .leftJoin(streamZ, (s, s2) -> {
                    logger.info("Join xy + z: {}-{}", s, s2);
                    return s + s2;
                }, JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(20)));
        stream.to("merged");
        return stream;
    }
```

If I only publish one message "msg" in topic z I was expecting a message consisting of nullnullmsg. However it doesn't seem to merge when the only input is z.

It seems there needs to be a message in topic x for the join to work but I need to join in a window from any topic.

**UPDATE 2**

Logically I needed an outerJoin:

```
    @Bean
    public KStream<String, String> joinedKStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
        KStream<String, String> streamX = kStreamBuilder.stream("x");
        streamX.peek((k, v) -> logger.info("x - key {} - value {}", k, v));
        KStream<String, String> streamY = kStreamBuilder.stream("y");
        streamY.peek((k, v) -> logger.info("y - key {} - value {}", k, v));
        KStream<String, String> streamZ = kStreamBuilder.stream("z");
        streamZ.peek((k, v) -> logger.info("z - key {} - value {}", k, v));

        //JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        JoinWindows joinWindow = JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceAndGrace(Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofSeconds(10));

        KStream<String, String> stream = streamX
                .outerJoin(streamY, (k, s, s2) -> {
                    logger.info("Join x + y: key {} - values {}-{}", k, s, s2);
                    return s + s2;
                }, joinWindow)
                .outerJoin(streamZ, (k, s, s2) -> {
                    logger.info("Join xy + z: key {} - values {}-{}", k, s, s2);
                    return s + s2;
                }, joinWindow);
        stream.foreach((key, value) -> logger.info("Merged key {} - value {}", key, value));
        stream.to("merged");
        return stream;
```

BUT there's still a problem:

I send "hey" to topic y and "you!" to topic z. A long time passes and nothing shows up in the merged topic.

At some point, after some more messages have been published, the join is performed and `nullheyyo!` shows up in the merged topic. Why this delay?

What's more if no knew messages are published in any topic, the previous ones are not joined. I expected that after the window period has finished, the merges would be automatically flushed.

Here's an example of what's going on:

- I publish 1:1 to topic x
- The xKStream logs: `x - key 1 - value 1`
- After the duration of the window + the grace period (15 secs) no join happens.
- I publish 2:2 to topic x
- Logs:

```
x - key 2 - value 2
Join x + y: key 1 - values 1-null
```

- As you can see, there's nothing about the second join yet.
- Finally when I publish another record 3:3 to x:

```
x - key 3 - value 3
Join x + y: key 2 - values 2-null
Join xy + z: key 1 - values 1null-null
Merged key 1 - value 1nullnull
```

Finally we get the merged log, and the joined record is flushed to the merged topic.

???

Comment: You could try joining a third stream with the output topic of two others

Comment: I've updated the question with the problem I found

Comment: How are you "publishing" data? Kafka producers don't immediately send unless you call flush function

Comment: I'm using the CLI: `./kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=:" --topic x`. When I write in the three topics, the merge is immediate. If I publish in just one, or two, nothing happens until more messages have been published in the three topics.

Comment: There's a `--sync` flag for the console producer. As mentioned, records aren't immediately flushed by a producer unless you explicitly do it

Comment: @OneCricketeer I appreciate your suggestion, however that doesn't seem to be the cause. Records were actually being sent to the topics but, for some reason, the full processing of the window is not performed until new out-of-the-window records arrive. I'm gonna provide a Github sample for anyone interested in this.

Comment: Sample added: https://github.com/codependent/kstream-multijoin